# The negation of “residue of $-1$ is a square modulo $p$” (p is prime)

Tags: abstract-algebra

My book told me its negation is $x^2+1$ is an irreducible element of $F_p$. I don’t get how these two statements are even related.

I have a feeling that it should be related to the fact that in a principal ideal domain if an element divides both $a$ and $b$ it divides their greatest common divisor given by the element that is equal to the ideal generated by $a$ and $b$.

Comment: how they're related:  if $a^2\equiv-1\pmod p$, then $(x-a)(x+a)\equiv x^2+1\pmod p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x^2+1$ could be written as a product of two linears it would mean that it would be of the form $(x+a)(x-a)=x^2-a^2$ which implies $a^2=-1$ i.e. $-1$ is a square mod $p$. Conversely, if $-1$ is a square of some element $a$, the polynomial $x^2+1$ can be written as $(x+a)(x-a)$.